# How convert Map<key ,value> to Map<value ,List<key>> in the simplest way possible

Tags: java, dictionary

```
Map<String, List<String>> convertMap = locationSynchronizeMap.entrySet().stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getValue, Collectors.mapping(Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
```

This is my solution。
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the issue with your solution?

Comment: I want to do it in the simplest way possible by Stream or some else.

Comment: What do you think could be improved?

Comment: Sorry , I don't know . I just want to know if it can be promoted. Tks!